# What happens when not_analyzed and analyzer is used in same mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-mapping

In elastic search mapping, as per my knowledge, `index:not_analyzed` means it indexes the value as it is with out analyzing.

and

When we want to specify an analyzer we can use `analyzer:<some-analyzer>`.

I've seen some people using both the settings for the same field like

```
"property":{
    "type":"string",
    "index":"not_analyzed",
    "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword"
 }
```

What is the effect of above setting, it seems contradictory to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

At least in ES 1.6 looks like if field is mapped to *not_analyzed* and the analyzer is specified it  overrides the *search_analyzer*.

i.e the mapping in OP is equivalent to

```
"property":{
    "type":"string",
    "index":"not_analyzed",
    "search_analyzer":"analyzer_keyword"
 }
```

A  field mapped as *not_analyzed* has the index analyzer always set to [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) The default search analyzer for *not_analyzed* is keyword however looks this can be overridden via analyzer/search_analyzer setting which honestly to me doesn't make sense.

Probably the mapping in OP was done to be compatible with earlier version ES  [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/229) where  looks like *standard analyzer* was the default search analyzer even for fields mapped as *not_analyzed*

Comment: So, in effect index:not_analyzed is ignored and the given analyzer is applied?

Comment: no only the search_analyzer is set to the analyzer that is given.search_analyzer is the analyzer that is used to analyze query terms while querying against the field in in match /multi-match etc